# Best non-alphanumeric characters for a directory/file

Tags: file, filesystems

I have a system with a lot of files. To avoid the configuration files/directories getting lost I try starting the configuration directories with a special character. However I keep falling into various gotchas in the process. I only need the character so that the files in question pop-up at the bottom or end in IDEs etc, so people can actually find them and distinguish them easily.

What's a good cross-platform, low-interferance, file/directory friendly, special characters? that doesn't require escaping and is easy to type.

Note: having the configuration split off would be better but unfortunately it's not an option because of how certain systems work with said files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minus and underscore:

```
-file-with-minus
_underscore_needs_two_fingers_for_shift
```

International available, Linux/Unix/OS-X/Dos/Win friendly.

Comment: @Alex: 0 and z are alphanumeric, so they violate the specification.

Comment: For the purpose of showing up at the top or bottom of the sorted file name list they are fine.

Comment: it is possible to have files like ZZlib something and so on, or 0MQ, though starting with number is forbidden in certain languages it's still usable in include files. I believe minus might be the best solution as user unknown suggested, answer accepted.

Comment: @Alex: If you don't like to answer the question at hand `with a special character`, `distinguish them easily`, `Best non-alphanumeric`, just wait for your favorite question to come along. Or give your comment as an answer, so I can vote it down. ;) If you rename a file 'action' to 'zaction' it will not be easily distinguishable and been sorted before/behind zappa, zoo, zztop and zugspitze.

Comment: Does + have special meaning in certain operating systems?

Comment: On Linux, the only forbidden characters are \0 (character 0) and / (slash); the first terminates Strings, the second is the directory delimiter. Other characters can be difficult to type - depending on your keyboard layout which is usually depending on your locale. In Germany, for example, `{` needs you typing the Alt-Gr modifier. In US/En afaik not. (But we can type äöüß nicely). Some Strings need escaping; the + on Linux doesn't, so I guess it doesn't on Unix/BSD/OS-X too.

Comment: ic, ty. I'll see if it causes issues :)